# Boundary regularity of solution to partial differential equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, regularity

I am conducting research on partial differential equations and I need a short-time existence result from the literature which I can not find at the moment. More precisely I would like to know the following:
In the book "Linear and Quasilinear Equations of Parabolic Type" by Ladyzenskaja and others the
following initial value problem is studied: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain and $S$ be its boundary. Furthermore we denote $\Omega_T:= \Omega \times [0, T)$ and $S_T:= S \times [0, T)$. We then study the initial value problem
$$
Lu=f, u\mid_{S_T}=0, u \mid_{t=0}= \psi_0(x) \, \, (*)$$
where $L$ is an operator of the form $Lu=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(a_{ij}u_{x_i}+a_iu)-b_iu_{x_i}-au$, with $a_{ij}(x, t)$ satisfying the inequality  $v \sum_{i=1}^n \zeta_i^2 \leq a_{ij} \zeta_i \zeta_j \leq \mu \sum_{i=1}^n \zeta_i^2$. 
One now has to introduce a concept of weak solutions for this equation:
We start with some definitions. We denote by $W^{1, 0}_2(Q_T)$ the Hilbert space with scalar product
$$ (u, v)_{W^{1, 0}(Q_T)}= \int_{Q_T} (uv+ u_{x_k}v_{x_k}) dx dt$$
and by $V_2(Q_T)$ the Banach space consisting of all elements of $W^{1, 0}_2(Q_T)$, which have a  finite norm
$$\vert u \vert_{Q_T}= \mbox{ess sup}_{0 \leq t \leq T} \left( \int_{\Omega} \vert u \vert^q dx \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}+ \left( \int_{Q_T} u_x^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Moreover we let $\mathring{V_2}(Q_T)$ be the closure of the smooth functions with compact support in $V_2(Q_T)$. \
Now we retun to the problem (*): We define a weak solution of (*) to be a function $u$ from $\mathring{V}_2(Q_T)$ which fulfills for almost all $t_1$ the identity 
$$I(t_1; u, \eta)= \int_{\Omega} \psi_0(x) \eta(x, 0) ds$$
where we let
$$I(t_1; u, \eta)= \int_{\Omega} u(x, t_1) \eta(x, t_1) dx- \int_0^{t_1} \int_{\Omega} u \eta_t dx dt+ \int_0^{t_1} (L_1(u, \eta)+ L_2(, \eta)) dt=0$$
with the abbreviations
$$L_1(u, \eta)= \int_M ((a_{ij}u_{x_j}+ a_iu)\eta_{x_i}+ (b_iu_{x_i}+au)\eta)dx$$
and
$$ L_2(f, \eta)=\int_M (f_i\eta_{x_i}+ f \eta)dx$$
Then it is shown in the book "Linear and Quasilinear Equations of Parabolic Type" by Ladyzenskaja and others that the problem (*) always has a weak solution which furthermore is contained in $C^{2+\alpha, 1+\frac{\alpha}{2}}(Q_T)$ provided that the coefficients $a_{ij}$, $b_i$, $c$ as well as the free terms $f$ and $\psi_0$ are elements of $C^{\alpha, \frac{\alpha}{2}}(Q_T)$ (this is precisely Theorem 12.1 in Chapter iii).
But what I can not find in the book is a statement about the regularity at the boundary, i.e. whether $u$ has to be continuous at the boundary or whatever.
\
I thus would like to know: Can somebody say anything about the regularity at the boundary? Is it continuous at least?

Comment: Anybody. who knows an answer

Comment: You could look at Lieberman's book.

Comment: Or cannon http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_1965_3_19_3_415_0.pdf